# Where can I learn more about LTE coverage and build out schedules in the US?

Tags: ipad, lte

I am looking for sites that do a good job of reviewing / documenting current LTE data coverage in the US. Where do the carriers have coverage maps and plans for build out documented? Also, are there any independent sources that measure actual performance and coverage so that we can educate ourselves about the options available for data on the new iPad?

Comment: I would say to look at the providers' websites, but I went poking around Verizon's site and found bupkis.

Comment: Apple will soon have links to the official coverage maps - but I'm also looking for analysis and synthesis of where the LTE build out plans for T and V really are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much in the way of a major community database of real-world speeds, sadly. Here are some other resources:

1. [Verizon's LTE coverage map](http://network4g.verizonwireless.com/pdf/VZW_4G_LTE_Coverage_Map.pdf)
2. [AT&T's HSPA+ coverage map](http://www.att.com/network/) (and [overview](http://www.att.com/network/assets/mrq_coverage.jpg))
3. [Overview of all major carriers](http://www.whatis4gservice.com/4g-coverage-maps/), and [another](http://www.fiercebroadbandwireless.com/special-reports/wimax-lte-and-hspa-comparing-operators-4g-coverage-areas) (older)
4. More general information on [current/planned deployments](http://ltemaps.org/)
5. [Verizon coverage map with speed tests](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&source=embed&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=201796584918211147824.0004974dca10b545fbdeb) - Minneapolis/St. Paul area only.

You might also use the [FCC's GIS data](http://wireless.fcc.gov/geographic/index.htm) to find out more about what towers already exist.  Presumably, they're not going to build new towers for LTE - just add antennae to existing sites.

Comment: Link #4 (http://ltemaps.org/) seems to be the best option for info on international deployments.